# Custom-drawing MapPoint maps in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, mappoint

My application requires an on-drive map as there will be no internet access during operation. I've kind of settled on using MapPoint 2009, but the map 'style' really clashes with my overall UI look and feel.

I'm wondering if there's some way to custom draw everything on the map (roads, labels, etc.)? It's crossed my mind that perhaps there's some themeing in the MapPoint application itself, but I don't have it handy right now :(

I'd totally prefer a WPF method but really, anything at this point helps :)

Comment: As an aside - you might want to check that your app doesn't constitute a "fleet" app; that has a different licensing model. Check the T&C document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe the MapPoint COM API exposes any method of overriding the default rendering.  You can add your own objects on top (via shapes, etc), but I don't believe it will do exactly what you are asking for.

The only C# mapping framework I know of that would do this is [SharpMap v2](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SharpMap%20v2).  The plans were to provide a WPF rendering stack in addition to the current GDI+ one.

Answer (score 4):

No, basically. The most you can do is add push-pins, lines, shapes etc. There is a usenet forum (microsoft.public.mappoint) that might have more, but I can pretty much guarantee the answer is "no".

Answer (score 0):

The only available map styles are those available through the GUI. Eg. there's a night time view, etc. Label font sizes can also be changed

MapPoint 2010 adds some additional styling in terms of what is displayed. Each feature class (rivers, large cities, medium sized cities, interstates, etc) can be off/normal/all. Along with the font size and general theme, these settings can be controlled through the API.